# uritemplate wcf webget - datetime parameter

Tags: wcf, uri, odata

Please help, I'm trying to pass datetime in the uri and I'm getting 
Bad Request - Error in query syntax error.
The uri is:
http://localhost:8090/service.svc/SpGet_Test()?ContactId=guid'0cf669a2-4d5f-e411-8037-002186299427'&AccountId=guid'0bf669a2-4d5f-e411-8037-002186299427'
&FromFileOpenDate='18/02/2015 00:00:00'

How can I pass a datetime parameter over uri?

Thank you in advanced